# Function to get distance and time between two location

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, return

Here i have a code below that will show google places API data when user click on marker.

I also have a two points-location with coordinates (lat,lng) so `Point1[], Point2[]`

How I can calculate road distance in km and time between this places and show in HTML.
Do google map have a function that will calculate this distance and time?

CODE:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){

        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            //class m_tooltip
            var contentStr = '<div><h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address+'</p>';
            if (!!place.photos) contentStr += '<img src='+place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 500, 'maxHeight': 500 })+'></img>';
            if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';

            var Point1 = [34,666, 56,888];
            var Point2 = [77.876, 45,555];
            contentStr += '<p>Distance in km:' + functionThatReturnRoadDistance(Point1, Point2) + '</p>';


            $(contentStr).dialog({
              modal:true
          });

          } else { 
            var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";

           $(contentStr).dialog();
          }  
        });
```

So is there some google map or similar function that will return me a distance in meter or kilometer not simple distance between places but ROAD/ROUTE distance ???

**UPDATE: I tru this:**

```
function calculateDistances(start,stop) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [start],
      destinations: [stop],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
  function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;


    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
       var xxx= "";
        xxx += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
     return xxx;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and to call it with:

```
  var start = document.getElementById("from").value;
        var stop = place.formatted_address;
        contentStr += '<p>'+ calculateDistances(start,stop); + '</p>';

        $(contentStr).dialog({
          modal:true
      });
```

but DONT work with DistanceMatrix

Comment: What have you tried? Here's a good starting point https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Comment: I try that but this is asinhron function so I cant call it for every popup window(dialog)

Comment: I update my question with what I try to do

Comment: I remember this question from earlier this week, I'm sure... Anyway, it looks like you need to include your modal call to within the callback function. I still have no idea what `asinhron` is, tho.

Comment: but how I can include modal call to callback function ???

Comment: also when I try this in console: calculateDistances(['New York'],['Chicago']);
Error: Error in property <origins>: (Invalid value at position 0: New York) I get error. so my function dont work ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === 'undefined')
{
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}

function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
    var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
    var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```

An example of the integration here : http://jsfiddle.net/dFqmG/ (result in km)

Comment: yes i know that, but this is not the road distance this is just straight (AIR) distance between places

Answer (score 0):

This can help you
[Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixRequests)

Comment: I know that, but I can't call this function in my popup dialog where is Point1,Point2 different every time, so somebody tell me that distanceMatrix is asinhrony and I cant call it in this way...

Comment: in console I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null